# BC550 Darlington Clipping

Tags: amplifier, analog

Evening Guys,

The amplifier shown below is clipping before the rails of my supply. I have narrowed the issue down to the Darlington pair before the Emitter Follower output stage and provided the PSpice output waveform. The goal of the project is to utilize a class A output stage so please don't suggest changing the output stage to B, AB, or D. Please help me allow the output to swing to approximately (+-15V).

For your convince here is the data sheet for the BC550 transistor.

BC550: https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/BC/BC547.pdf

[image: Schematic]
[image: Output Waveform]

Lastly in case you would like the Cadence project or larger images, here is an FTP link:

ftp://ftpAdmin:Aa1@67.240.161.199:21/EE%20Stack%20Exchange/BC550%20Darlington%20Saturating/

I sincerely appreciate the help I receive here,

-Ryan Selby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The voltage across C3 (9 v) fixes the quiescent current through R9 at about 10 mA, for a quiescent voltage across R9 of ~1 volt. Any negative swing less than this will reverse bias the Darlington BE junctions, clipping the output. So you can only allow a 2 V pk-pk signal at the base of Q9. The rest follows.

And your gain is not as high as you think it ought to be because of the loading by the Thevenin equivalent of R11/R12 through C4.

Comment: Ahhh thank you very much, I suppose I could also provide a better solution with a current source below the Darlington pair as this will allow the emitter to swing lower than 9 volts correct?

Comment: Actually, no. That will simply force the Darlington to operate at whatever the current source is pulling. Then your gain would become 1, as the emitter current plus the base current would remain constant.

Comment: Alright, Ill change the gain of the first stage and the emitter resistance ratio.

Comment: You're fighting a losing battle doing that. About the best you'll do is 20 volts. Also, increase R11 and R12 by a factor of 100.

Comment: So if I am understanding this correctly id need a higher supply voltage if I wanted the output to swing further?

Comment: Yes. Put it this way. If your desired input to this stage is +/- 2 volts, that means the emitter will have to swing 4 volts total. Then you need an emitter resistor to convert the base voltage swing to current, and let's say it needs another 2 volts total. Finally, when the Darlington is full on, the emitter/collector drop will be about 2 volts. The total across the Darlington/emitter resistor combination is about 8 volts, which leaves about 22 volts for a load swing (best case).

Comment: Your bias resistors are much too low and loading the previous stages.  Since you are using darlington connected transistors you don't need to account for much base current so the resistors can be higher in value.